# Legend styling in QGIS: How to create overlaying points based on size

Tags: qgis, style, legend

I have a categorized point layer, were the size of the points is based on a feature. Normally in the legend, there would appear multiple points with different sizes. However they consume a lot of space. I would like to have the points one on top of another (see picture below). 
Is that possible without having to do it all manually?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I found a solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287514/missing-size-scaled-symbols-in-map-layout-legend): "*On the bottom right of the layer styling panel you select Advanced > Data-defined Size Legend and enable the collapsed or separated legend according to your needs*"