# Data-defined size legend QGIS and Map Unit symbol

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-3, legend

In QGIS, I am making maps of the same project in different scale (global and local). To make my symbol looks alike in all scales, I've choose to use proportional symbol with a size in "map unit".

Therefore I have now a problem with the "Data-defined size legend" as my symbol are just way too enormous in the legend.

How to get this right?

[image]

Comment: Related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287514/qgis-composer-symbol-size/287547?noredirect=1#comment460764_287547

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that has been reported at: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19282