# Using graduate and categorize in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, csv

I'm using a .csv detailing types of renewable energy in the UK. I want to display them as different colours for the types of energy (e.g. wind, solar, gas etc.) but also a different size symbol based on the energy output.

All the information is in the .csv file and I am able to perform these two styles independently, but I can't work out how to do this together.  I'm new to GIS so just getting the hang of things!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thats not difficult to do but a little tricky.

---

**Option 1**

1. First open symbology menu of your layer and create a `categorized` symbology.

[image]

2. Now click on `categorized` and change it to `rule-based`.

[image]

As you can see your categories are converted to rules.

3. Now you can add a graduated renderer to each rule. `Mark` a category and click on `Refine Selected Rules` and choose `Add Ranges to Rule`.

[image]

4. Now set up the graduated style as you like and click `ok`.

[image]

5. I suggest to now remove the symbol of the category. Doubleclick it an `uncheck Symbol` (it is not absolutely necessary, but I suggest to do so):

[image]

6. The result:

[image]

[image]

---

**Option 2**

In case you have houndreds of categories I suggest to add the style to each feature and use `data defined override` like this:

1. Choose `Categorized` in Symbology menu and click `Change...`. Now click on `Data defined override` next to size (or color) and choose `Assistant`.

[image]

2. Choose your `field` you want to the graduated renderer to be based on. Then choose `min/max values` (automatically or manually).

[image]

3. Finally `Classify` your symbols. The result:

[image]

[image]

Using option 2 there is no legend showing the size. Also see [Why are size-scaled symbols missing from map layout legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287514/why-are-size-scaled-symbols-missing-from-map-layout-legend)

Comment: Bizarrely, both the Categorize and Graduated style options have stopped working for the .csv file I am using, despite the file not changing. I have tried starting a new map and it doesn't make a difference, I'm wondering if this is a bug?

Comment: @Wiredchild Can't really tell from here. Only guess I can make: Make sure to use the correct decimal separator when loading the CSV. There is a checkbox you need to tick when they are separated by comma. Otherwise the fields are not correctly recognized as numeric. On a second thought that does not explain why categorized does not work.

Comment: Hi, I've just sorted it thanks it wasn't recognising the field! However, the symbols I applied to the categorization (a series of different shapes) when I use the rule-based to add graduate these categories these aren't the symbol that becomes larger/smaller based on the value. They all become circles, how can I stop this? Thanks for your help it is much appreciated!

Comment: This is after categorization and these are the symbols i want to change size in-line with the graduation values I'm using: https://imgur.com/qwxAgn9

Instead, this happens: https://imgur.com/n44hxee

Comment: you need to set up your symbol within "Add ranges to rule" click on "change symbol". See [Screenshot](https://abload.de/img/1x9jd1.jpg) Additionally I suggest to remove the categorized symbol as mentioned in my 5th screenshot in my answer above as this can lead to conflicts/2symbols.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Is it best to use 'Natural Breaks' as you displayed? For context the map is renewable energy projects across the UK, the symbols are the types (wind, hydro etc.) whilst the size if the amount of power they create in MW. 

The vast majority (solar for example) produce very little (less than 10MW), whilst a small handful (mainly offshore wind) produce up to 1,000s of MW. I'm wondering what would be a good number breaks so that it is an easily legible map?

Comment: I've also just noticed that if I create graduation separately the categories are not relational to each other in size. The sizes are only relational to the shapes in their individual categories.

Comment: Yes, you cannot do this automatically when using categorized and graduated as a combination. You need to set up or adjust sizes manually. Since all categories use MW as unit this should be no problem doing it as follows: Pick out the max and min values (of overall categories) and create a fitting scale. For this usecase I'd recommend Equal Interval. Use the absolute minimum as first value and the absolute maximum as last value. Use the same Intervalls for all classes. However, this is a complex cartographic decision. It probably fits better into a new question instead of comments.

Comment: Ok, I will play around until something fits suitably! Final question (i promise!) I need to export the final shapes as a .dxf to open in AutoCAD. When I do so it just exports the image as single points. Is there a way to do this so they come through as the shapes displayed in QGIS? Perhaps converting these to vector shapes or something?

Comment: Sorry, cant really help you there as I have never used AutoCAD. You can export as .dxf, .svg or vector pdf.

Comment: OK no worries, thank you so much for your help so far!