# Setting different symbols for a CSV layer with attribute "Type"

Tags: qgis-3, layers, symbology, csv

I have a CSV file with columns:

- Name
- Latitude
- Longitude
- Type (values: Hotel, View)

I have this displaying correctly with Name displayed by each point. I would like to have different symbols according to Type (Type is either Hotel or View).  I have tried to use Symbology/Categorized but was unable to construct a suitable formula.  Is this the correct procedure or is there another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What have you tried with 'categorized' symbology. It should work fairly easily with your two Type values (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308378/using-graduate-and-categorize-in-qgis)

Comment: I'll try that, I was using categorised and trying to construct a formula on the value line.

Comment: If you click Classify it should find your two possible values, you can then customize each symbol

Comment: Did find that after you gave the link, works well.

Comment: Not only should the very helpful comments be an Answer, but it should also be noted that, using the Legend feature in the same config, you actually create multiple layers for the CSV, with an expand-icon in the layer list. Very useful, and easy, albeit hard to find info. Glad I found it here

Answer (score 2):

I have created a set of points with a field "type" in the attribute with 2 unique values "Hotel" and "View".

[image]

[image]

Opened the layer property box, selected the Symbology Tab and from the Symbology type I selected categorized Symbology.

[image]

Clicked on Classify and all the symbology was created based on the unique value in the field.There is no formula to be added.

[image]

You can modify them at your will one by one.

The same would work if I loaded the file from a CSV containing coordinates.